# How to connect 20 DS18B20 temperature sensors to RPi?

Tags: sensor, temperature

RPi is working fine with 10 1-wire temperature sensors, but I need to connect 20.

Comment: Can you post how you are connecting them and what issue you encounter when trying to connect more than 10?  According to [this Adafruit posting](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/ds18b20) it is possible to connect multiple DS18B20 sensors in parallel, but it doesn't specify if there is a limit.

Comment: Add this line of code to: /etc/modules

    wire max_slave_count=20

Answer (score 1):

See [Guidelines for Reliable Long Line 1-Wire Networks](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/148)

> Two simple terms describe measurements that are critical to 1-Wire network performance: radius and weight.
>
> - The radius of a network is the wire distance from the master end to the most distant slave. It is measured in meters.
> - The weight of a network is the total amount of connected wire in the network. It is also measured in meters.
>
> For example, a star network configuration with three branches of 10m, 20m, and 30m would have a radius of 30m (i.e., the distance from 1-Wire master to the furthest slave) and a weight of 60m (i.e., the total length of wire in the network, 10m + 20m + 30m).
>
> In general, the weight of the network limits the rise time on the cable, while the radius establishes the timing of the slowest signal reflections.

---

> Testing has shown that unswitched star-type network topologies (i.e., those with several branches diverging at the master) are the most difficult to make reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a i2c 8 channel 1-wire rpi hat.
http://www.sheepwalkelectronics.co.uk/product_info.php?cPath=22&products_id=67

It performs tons quicker then the bitbangging way the pi does it. 
I would also recommend using owfs (One Wire File System). Which essentially does the same thing as what Raspbian has done in creating a directory where your 1-wire devices are.
http://owfs.sourceforge.net/index_old.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a limit on w1 wire module to 10 sensors.

I find this information but i don't test it for the moment

[visit this post here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=6649&start=200)

> If you or anyone else are still wondering how to attach more than 10
>   devices, just load the module with the following argument:
>
> `modprobe wire max_slave_count=15`
>
> or in /etc/modules with simply
>
> `wire max_slave_count=15`